# Is there a way to kill all recent apps with a shell command at once?

Tags: android, shell, android-tv

I am using keymapper to try to map a button to kill recent apps because I can open the shelf but not close them with my remote.

I have thought a simple alt f4 would do the trick unfortunately the application does not have keyboard shortcuts.

I was hoping there is a shell command that I could map to a key which will kill all recent apps.

Any help would be appreciated.

I've tried pressing all the keys on my remote and remapping long presses but I can not find an option to remap either mouse or keyboard input to my remote

```
am kill recent
app recent not found
```

(edit i have the start.ca IPBS9510 running 8.0 / 5 July 2018 Kernel 4.9.61 inspur@s99 #1 Build OPR6.170623.013.1.1.0 release-keys)

Answer (score 0):

i dont think am kill recent will work, unless your package name is "recent".

the correct command usgae should be like this:

```
am kill <package>
am kill-all
```

**am kill:** Kill all processes associated with .  Only kills.
  processes that are safe to kill -- that is, will not impact the user
  experience.

**am kill-all:** Kill all background processes.

P.s: get the list of current active process, then traverse it to get the package name.

Comment: hi, when i do am kill-all it says applet not found as well. will i have to make a shell command with the name of all the packages i regularily use and kill them all?

Comment: i would go with second option. find out the list of packages and then issue a kill command